# Iterating through a list to add values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to add a `txt` file to a list in Python, then iterate through the list finding the numbers and adding them all together.

**sample text:**

```
Alabama 4780
Alaska 710
Arizona 6392
Arkansas 2916
California 37254
Colorado 5029
```

**expected output:**

```
['Alabama', '4780', 'Alaska', '710', 'Arizona', '6392', 'Arkansas', '2916', 'California', '37254', 'Colorado', '5029']

total population: 57621
```

I can add them to the list just fine but am unable to find the total of all the numbers.
Ideally I'd like to have it all in one function.

```
def totalpoplst(filename):
    lst = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            lst += line.strip().split(' ')
        return print(lst)
    totalpop()

def totalpop(filename):
    total_pop = 0
    for i in lst:
        if  i.isdigit():
            total_pop = total_pop + i.isdigit()
    return print(total_pop)

def main():
    filename = input("Please enter the file's name: ")
    totalpoplst(filename)

main()
```

Comment: does your file have two newlines??

Comment: no its just one new line, the text goes state name without spaces followed by a space then the population number

Comment: I know it is long to read, but there is a great python tutorial here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ and here: http://pymotw.com/2/contents.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `dict` for key-value data structures than a list.

```
>>> population = {}
>>> total = 0
>>> with open('list.txt', 'r') as handle:
...     for line in handle:
...         state, sep, pop = line.partition(' ')
...         population[state] = int(pop)
...         total += population[state]
... 
>>> total
57081
```

Comment: Quick question lest say I wanted to use a set(). How do add each line from the text file to the set?

Comment: why would you use a set? A set is not an associative array. Most people use a set for homogeneous data, e.g. a set of keys or a set of values. A set is similar to a dictionary except you cannot attach data to each element. In your example, you could use a set for the states, but you then wouldn't be able to have data (population) attached to each state.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the population supplied as a string to a number. To do this change the line from:

```
total_pop = total_pop + i.isdigit()
```

to read:

```
total_pop = total_pop + int(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open('your_file.txt')  
your_dict={}
total_pop = 0
for x in f:
    x=x.strip()
    s,p=x.split(' ')
    your_dict[s]=p
    total_pop +=int(p)
print your_dict
print total_pop
```

Dictionary to use will be better

Comment: ahh it was a typing mistake